# CPP: Use map for multidimensionality?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, data-structures

I want to build a 3D grid and use a multidimensional map, which holds the nodes, something like:

```
std::map<double, std::map<double, std::map<double, pathplanning::Node*> > >
```

The three doubles are the (x,y,z) position in the grid, the `Node` datatype is a simple class, which capsules some information.

I'm new at the cpp community and i want to ask: is that a good way? Or should i use some different datastructures? Here is why i don't use a multidimensional array: the positions could be negative, the array index can't.

Comment: If you have a sparse matrix (i.e. lots more grid cells that `Node` values) then this would be okay, if you have a dense matrix, I would discourage this kind of container for performance. You'll have tons of cache misses.

Comment: why don't you define your own class (i.e. `point3d`) to use as your map key?

Comment: If you only need them to be negative (not fractional), why don't you use `int`?

Comment: @mescalinum: Yeah, you're right. I will do that. Thought a bit too complex ;-)

Comment: @Cássio Renan: It is a greater project and the positions have to be double (was not my decision).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My opinion is no.

Use a std::map (without the pointer). vector3d is any structure holding 3 double ordered somehow. A possibility is

```
struct vector3d
{
   double x ;
   double y ; 
   double z ;
} ;
```

with a

```
bool operator<(const vector3d lhs, const vector3d &rhs)
{
   if (lhs.x != rhs.x)
      return lhs.x < rhs.x ;
   if (lhs.y != rhs.y)
      return lhs.y < rhs.y ;
    return lhs.z < rhs.z ;
}
```

Comment: In the case the user cares about repeated points then this solution is not correct because the repetitions will not be represented in the map.

Comment: In this context repeated points would be based on floating point equality...which would require in turn forther analysis

Answer (score 3):

That data structure can be fine, you may consider to store smart pointer instead of raw one not to deal with memory management manually. But depends on situation it could be more efficient to use structure with three coordinates as a key for a single map:

```
struct 3d {
    double x, y, z;
    bool operator<( const 3d &r ) const;
}

std::map< 3d, pathplanning::Node*> map;
```

`std::tuple<double, double, double>` can be used as well. This will eliminate 2 additional lookups for data access and probably would be more cache friendly.

On another side if you need performance but do not care about order you may consider `std::unordered_map`, but in that case you would have to implement `std::hash` specialization for 3d structure. Or you can use 3 nested `std::unordered_map`.

Answer (score 2):

You could also try using a `unordered_multimap< gridPos, pathfinder::Node* >` and use a mapping function of the 3D `gridPos` into 1D, a nice article about how to do this with hash tables can be found here (http://matthias-mueller-fischer.ch/publications/tetraederCollision.pdf).

For an explanation on how to write a custom hash function for STL containers you can visit http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/user-defined-hash-functions-for-unordere/231600210 and follow the advise presented there.

Then inside the multimap you can store your `pathfinder::Node` data or pointers as you see fit and query the structure using the mapping of the 1D `gridPos` to 3D.

Hope that helps.